# Hot reload using Node and React with Lerna

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, docker, lerna

I have a lerna monorepository with React, shared packages and Node backend. To make it easier for dev team to work, I run it all in docker. But I face 2 issues:

1. Hot reload doesn't work for me in docker for node application
2. React rebuilds, but sometimes changes not reflected in browser

Here is my docker compose

```
version: "3.8"
services:
    efm-mysql:
        image: mysql
        restart: always
        environment:
            MYSQL_USER:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD:
            MYSQL_PASSWORD:
            MYSQL_DATABASE:
            MYSQL_HOST: localhost
        ports:
            - "3306:3306"
        volumes:
            - ./servers/db/sample.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/sample.sql
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD", 'mysqladmin', 'ping', '-uroot', '-p***' ]
            timeout: 5s
            interval: 5s
            retries: 10

    manager-be:
        container_name: manager-be
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                SERVICE: servers/manager-be
            target: builder
        volumes:
            - ./packages:/app/packages
            - /app/servers/manager-be/node_modules
            - ./servers/manager-be:/app/servers/manager-be
        command: npx nodemon --exec --legacy-watch "cd servers/manager-be && yarn start"
        env_file:
            - ./servers/manager-be/.env
        ports:
            - 3008:3000
        depends_on:
            efm-mysql:
                condition: service_healthy

    manager-fe:
        container_name: manager-fe
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            target: builder
            args:
                SERVICE: front-end/manager-fe
        volumes:
            - ./packages:/app/packages
            - /app/front-end/manager-fe/node_modules
            - ./front-end/manager-fe:/app/front-end/manager-fe
        command: npx nodemon --exec "cd front-end/manager-fe && yarn start"
        env_file:
            - ./front-end/manager-fe/.env
        ports:
            - 4002:3000
```

DockerFile

```
FROM node:lts-alpine as builder
ARG SERVICE
WORKDIR /app
RUN chown -R node:node /app
COPY tsconfig.json /app

USER node

COPY --chown=node:node package*.json yarn.lock lerna.json ./
COPY --chown=node:node packages/ ./packages
COPY --chown=node:node ${SERVICE} ./${SERVICE}
RUN yarn --frozen-lockfile
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["yarn", "--prefix", "${SERVICE}", "start"]

FROM node:lts-alpine
ARG SERVICE
WORKDIR /app
COPY --chown=node:node --from=builder /app .

EXPOSE 3000
CMD cd servers/manager-be/ && yarn start
```